# Failed to bring up eth1:1 when using secondary private IP on secondary network interface on VPC instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC ec2 instance (t1.micro), in which I have two network interfaces, the primary `eth0` and additional `eth1`.

I was able to bring up the `eth1` by editing the **/etc/network/inteface**

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

However, when I enable the secondary IP on this interface, I get the error 
**"Failed to bring up eth1:1"**

```
auto eth1:1
iface eth1:1 inet dhcp
```

I can find this secondary IP is being assigned on the ec2 "**Manage Private IP**", so what would be the reason?

Comment: not posting this as an answer since I'm not 100% sure.. but i don't think you can use dhcp on an aliased interface. It has to be a static ip like `iface eth1:1 inet static` then your static ip options below that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign IPs to virtual interfaces via DHCP, they have to be statically assigned. The reason is that for a DHCP server, there's only one device `eth1` that's indistiguishable from `eth1:1` (because they share the same MAC).

You can statically assign an IP this way:

```
auto eth1:1
iface eth1:1 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
```